# Google has updated its Analytics tag. (gtag,js). Do i have to delete the old google analytics tags on my websites?

Tags: javascript, tags, analytics

Google has updated its Analytics tag. (gtag,js). They tell me to put it in after the Head tag.

Do I have to delete the old google analytics tags on my websites first?. I am a neophyte, not a programmer, so am not even sure that the following codes are relevant.

```
Old google code for first website:

<script type="text/javascript">



  var _gaq = _gaq || [];

  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-47733910-1']);

  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'buzzwordbooks.com']);

  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);



  (function() {

    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;

    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

  })();



</script>


The second one is this:

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-52162192-1', 'bookbooster.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I am too scared to try anything without advice.